# how to properly use pytest mark.parametrize decorator when passing arguments for other decorators (e.g fixtures, mocks)?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

when I tried to use mark.parametrize along with other decorators as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def some_fixture()
 db = create_db()
 yield db
 db.close()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('id, expected',[(1,1),(2,2)])
@mock.patch('some_module')
def some_test(mock_module, id, expected, db):
 mock_module.function.return_value = 1
 connection = db.connection()
 assert expected my_function(id, connection)
```

I have two questions:

- **general one:** what is the natural order to put the arguments and to order the decorators in case of having more than one?
- **specific to above code:** why do I get error: `missing 2 required positional arguments` for both `id` and `expected` even though they are supplied as shown?

Comment: Your example code is erroneous and doesn't reflect the error you described. E.g. the function defs miss colons, the `db` fixture is missing etc. Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Use `some_fixture` in place of `db` in the argument and in the body of test function. 
Order of argument does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

When using patch, parametrize and fixtures altogether, the order is important:
Fists should be mention patched values, in reverse order, then parametrized values and fixtures in the end in any order.

```
@pytest.fixture
def some_fixture1()
    pass

@pytest.fixture
def some_fixture2()
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('id, expected',[(1,1),(2,2)])
@mock.patch('some_module1')
@mock.patch('some_module2')
@mock.patch('some_module3')
def some_test(
   some_module3, 
   some_module2, 
   some_module1, 
   id, 
   expected,
   some_fixture1,
   some_fixture2,
):
    pass
```

Comment: Worth noting that if a (function scoped) fixture takes an argument, that argument can be provided (with the same name) from `pytest.mark.parametrize`. It's not necessary to pass the parameter to the test function.